# SBT Warning For Deprecated Commands

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm wondering how do I change the following which gives me a warning for deprecation for the

> in

command?

```
lazy val enablingCoverageSettings = Seq(coverageEnabled in(Test, compile) := true, coverageEnabled in(Compile, compile) := false)
```

I guess I have to use the syntax

> This

but how do I change it in my case here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to transform it to:

```scala
lazy val enablingCoverageSettings = Seq(
  Test / compile / coverageEnabled := true,
  Compile / compile / coverageEnabled := false
)
```

The idea is to replace `x in (y, z)` with `y / z / x`.